# How to highlight part of a webpage by blurring the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website where I want to achieve the following behavior:

- if someone clicks on a particular item (image or swf) everything else on the page would either disappear or blur out.
- this way the only thing left on the page that is visible is the thing that was just clicked

  Is this possible to make everything change except this one div?

Comment: Remember to set the `wmode=transparent` to the flash/swf objects in order to let the browser 'blur' them out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this effect is achieved by setting the z-index of the 'selected' item to a very high value, then adding a position:fixed div to the page that covers the entire page and has a z-index just lower than the selected item.  It's generally referred to as a 'modal div'. Searching for 'modal' along with your JS framework of choice will return you a number of usable solutions almost out of the box.

Comment: And if jQuery 1.3+ happens to be your framework of choice, ColorBox is quite lovely: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a modal.  Check out the jqueryui dialog widget's modal option:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal